# Eclipse - Why the "Show Whitespace" toolbar item is grayed out in the XML editor but not in the Java one?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

Xml:

[image: Xml Selected]

Java:

[image: Java File Selected]

Is it a bug or a feature?

Needless to say the shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) works fine when the XML file is selected.

**Software version used:**

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>
> Version: Luna M7 Release (4.4.0M7) Build id: 20140508-1440

Comment: You can open a Java file enable 'Show Whitespace Characters' and afterwards open the XML file (or switch tabs). But this sounds like a bug to me (or a missing feature).

Comment: @Absurd-Mind: I can use the shortcut anyway

Comment: Asked at the eclipse site: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1387637/#msg_1387637

Comment: Apparently it looks to work now on Mars version (Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)) I just needed to add the toolbar on the perspective.

Comment: @ruffp: I'll have to test but meanwhile you could add  an answer with what you did in details

Answer (score 6):

My solution is to use the latest Eclipse version (Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)) which seems to work properly.

The only operations to do for the XML files is to add the button to the toolbar like this:

1. Use or open the `Java EE` Perspective
2. Open any xml file in a project (e.g. blueprint.xml)
3. Go to menu: `Windows`-> `Perspective` -> `Customize Perspective`
4. In the opened dialog window, choose the tab `Action Set Availability`
5. In the column `Available action sets:` check the `Editor Presentation`
6. Press OK button to close the popup window.

Here is the windows dialog after checking the right option:

[image: Customize Perspective Screenshot]

The three buttons appears now in the toolbar, not greyed-out.

UPDATE: However I found that if I open a pom.xml file the button is still greyed-out, but if I open another plain xml (blueprint.xml or one from a test) it is not.

It seems there is a [bug](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1409) with the pom viewer. As a workaround, I created a key shortcut (e.g AltGr + W) and it works in the pom.xml as well with the shortcut.